# In which case can HttpContext.Request.ContentType be null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http

HttpContext.Request.ContentType is nullable type `string?`.
So I have to do something like that:

```
string contentType = HttpContext.Request.ContentType;
bool isJson = contentType?.StartsWith(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json) ?? false;
```

Can it be null? In which case?

Comment: `HttpContext.Request` looks the same for payload with and without body ... according RFC `Content-Type` is "required as SHOULD" only for payload with body

Answer (score 1):

From the decompiled soure code for httpContext.Request

AS you can see, contentType is a string, which if not assigned a value is `null`. When returning reading/getting content type, if it has not been assigned a value, `string.empty` is returned.

So, to answer your question, yes and no, however you should never get a null from ContentType, rather you will always get a `String.Empty' instead.

The exception here would be if request is null in which case request and all of its properties would be null.

[Null String MSDN for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.8.1#Nulls)

```
    public string ContentType
        {
            get
            {
                if (_contentType == null)
                {
                    if (_wr != null)
                    {
                        _contentType = _wr.GetKnownRequestHeader(12);
                    }

                    if (_contentType == null)
                    {
                        _contentType = string.Empty;
                    }
                }

                return _contentType;
            }
            set
            {
                _contentType = value;
            }
        }
```